# How do I replace or remove: "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" and any white space from the html text In CYPRESS

Tags: cypress

**Assertion Error**

> 25 | ReceiptPage.getPageIntro().should('have.text', this.data.receiptPageIntro)

expected <div.hco_introbox> to have text: "In this section, the settings for Relay Response, Silent Post, and Receipt Link are set. These settings dictate receipt display and how transactional data is transmitted back to the merchant".,

but the text was: "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t In this section, the settings for Relay Response, Silent Post, and Receipt Link are set. These settings dictate receipt display and how transactional data is transmitted back to the merchant. \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

Comment: please add the code you tried along with the HTML of your element.

Comment: Where was the value of the text assigned? Isn't that the place to correct it? Or are you asking how to include (allow) arbitrary whitespace in the allow text?

Comment: I am just asking how to remove white space and  line breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `contains.text` instead so it will be  :

```
ReceiptPage.getPageIntro().should('contains.text', this.data.receiptPageIntro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, you can also use `include.text` as well.

```js
ReceiptPage.getPageIntro().should('include.text', this.data.receiptPageIntro)
```